# Flask sqlalchemy relations across multiple files

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask Sqlalchemy and I want to declare multiple models and relate them to each other, I followed the example in the documentation but I keep getting this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Organization->organizations,
expression 'User' failed to locate a name ('User').
If this is a class name,
consider adding this relationship()
to the <class 'models.Organization.Organization'>
class after both dependent classes have been defined
```

I don't want to store all my models in one files as the project might get bigger and bigger with time, so I've created the following structure:

```
- models
--- __init__.py
--- User.py
--- Organization.py
--- ...
- manage.py
- app.py
```

I want the user to belong to an Organization, and the Organization has many users, also I want the Organization to have an optional field for itself reflexive relationship, here is what I've tried.

**init**.py

```
from .Attachment import Attachment
from .Invoice import Invoice
from .Organization import Organization
from .Setting import Setting
from .Transaction import Transaction
from .User import User
```

User.py

```
from app import db, ma
from marshmallow_enum import EnumField
import enum
import bcrypt


class RuleEnum(enum.Enum):
    admin = 'admin',
    collector = 'collector'
    retailer = 'retailer'
    vendor = 'vendor'
    vendor_admin = 'vendor_admin'


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    mobile = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.TEXT(), nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    rule = db.Column(db.Enum(RuleEnum), nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())

    # relations

    #related fields
    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizations.id'), nullable=True)


    def __init__(
            self,
            name,
            username,
            mobile,
            password,
            rule,
            is_active,
            organization_id = None
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.rule = rule
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.organization_id = organization_id
        self.password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<id %s>" % self.id


class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    rule = EnumField(RuleEnum, by_value=True)
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['password']
        model = User
        load_instance = True
```

Organization.py

```
from app import db, ma
import enum
from marshmallow_enum import EnumField


class TypeEnum(enum.Enum):
    vendor = 'vendor'
    retailer = 'retailer'


class Organization(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'organizations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    cr = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String())
    is_request_approved = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    type = db.Column(db.Enum(TypeEnum))
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())

    # relations

    # virtual columns
    parent = db.relationship('Organization', remote_side=id, backref='sub_organizations')
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='organization')

    # related fields
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizations.id'), nullable=True)

    def __init__(
            self,
            name,
            cr,
            location,
            is_request_approved,
            is_active,
            type,
            parent_id = None
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.cr = cr
        self.location = location
        self.is_request_approved = is_request_approved
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.type = type
        self.parent_id = parent_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<id %s>" % self.id


class OrganizationSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    type = EnumField(TypeEnum, by_value=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        load_instance = True
```

Regarding the migrations I've followed a blog post and made the `manage.py` file with this code

manage.py

```
import os

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db

app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy - multiple files - relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767241/sqlalchemy-multiple-files-relationships)

Comment: Can you share also your exact stacktrace?

Comment: I see in examples here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html that remote_side is specified as list. Can not be an issue, but worth trying.

Comment: nah, it worked perfectly, turned out the problem was the import of the models itself, I have to import them in order in my `__init__.py` file so the classes would be available when calling the `relationship` method, really appreciated you're help .. @merrydeath

Answer (score 3):

For future reference I solved it by arranging the import statements in my `__init__.py` file, so that any class that might be referred to in a relationship shall be imported before so in my case I had to change the `__init__.py` file to the following

```
from .User import User # User class is imported before it's referenced in the Organization model
from .Attachment import Attachment
from .Invoice import Invoice
from .Organization import Organization
from .Setting import Setting
from .Transaction import Transaction
```

it's not the ideal solution I'm sure there's a better way so any other/better approach is welcomed for future references.

Comment: Can confirm this still works on May 18, 2022. The ```__init__.py``` being referenced here is the one located in the ```models``` folder. Cheers.